# How to fit a linear regression line in a log-log axis in R plot?

Tags: r

I would like to fit a linear trend line in a log-log axis in R plot. Here is the sample code:

```
a<-c(1:20);
b<-c(21:40);
plot(a,b,log='xy');
fit<-lm(b~a);
abline(fit,col="blue",lwd=2);
```

However it fails to plot the trend line.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53360743/how-to-add-trend-line-in-a-log-log-plot-ggplot2/53361308#53361308

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lines` instead of `abline`:

```
# Data (with a random component on y)
set.seed(1234)
x <- c(1:20)
y <- c(21:40)+rnorm(length(x))
plot(x, y, log='xy')

# Fit the linear models on the logarithms of x and y
dts <- data.frame(logx=log(x), logy=log(y))
fit <- lm(logy~logx, data=dts)

# Plot the linear model
dts$predlogy <- predict(fit, newdata=dts)
lines(exp(dts$logx), exp(dts$predlogy))
```

[image]

Comment: I was looking a way to fit a linear regression line.

Comment: @user28725 Yes, this is a linear regression line plotted on a log-log scale. Of course, it does not look like a line... Maybe are trying to fit a linear model on the transformed variables log(y) vs log(x) ?

Comment: Yes, I was looking the way to fit linear model on the transformed axis.

Comment: @user28725 OK. See my edited answer. Hope it can help you.